# UI issue with Prism MasterDetail implementation

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, master-detail

I am using github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/Sandbox/Xamarin/HelloWorld to implement MasterDetail using Prism.

I have successfully ran the example and all is fine but the menu is covering phone top notification area. How can I solve this?

[Please see the issue here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGwgP.png)

In Xamarin example https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/MasterDetailPage/

this issue is not happending.

Do I have to do some addition trick with Prism that is not done in HelloWorld example?

Thanks
Tadas

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/473 check this

Comment: I can see there was a bug in xamarin.forms which seems or seems not to be fixed... Thank you for this but what should I do about it?

Comment: And why Xamarin example just works?

Comment: did you tried giving padding ?

Comment: Yes Sahil. That is what I did at the end. On MasterPage I added a stack with top Margin like this <StackLayout Margin="0,25,0,0"> and also on content page I added a trasparent background like this          <ContentPage  BackgroundColor="Transparent"> Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is an old sample that does not use Material Design.  All the newer Xamarin.Forms templates utilize material design which result in the master showing over the topmost bar.  You could also try playing with the MasterBehavior property to control how the master behaves.

Comment: Hello Mr. Lagunas and thank you for a reply and thank you for your perfect software that give country boy like me a chance to make some money on software. I hope all is good for you. You should be proud of yourself everyday.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words.